# Woocommerce Setting missing "Pages" Tab

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, settings

It seems that the pages tab in my woocommerce settings is missing. While I can see videos online has this tab.

[Version shown online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKiS7.png)

Here is the version I have. I know the versions may differ but I don't think the newest one does not have the "pages" tab in setting.

[my version of Woocommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoYhs.png)

Is there anything I can do to make the "pages" tab appear in the settings of Woocommerce?

Comment: By default, There is no "Pages" tab in Woocommerce setting… So this feature in your first screen shot is maid by a plugin or some custom code…

Comment: Just look at the styling of the dashboard - that's an incredibly ancient screenshot!